# Logstash _dateparsefailure matching timestamp with date plugin

Tags: date, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I have a json input with the String field `timestamp` that I want to parse to date in the field `@timestamp` in elasticsearch.

The input `timestamp` field: `2021-06-20 03:37:14.595000+00:00`

This is how I've set up the filter in logstash:

```
date {
        match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+ZZ:ZZ", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
```

The input string is in ISO8601 format, so using only "ISO8601" should work. However, I'm getting the _dateparsefailure. Therefore, I've also tried with the patterns "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+ZZ:ZZ" and "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", with no luck.

I've also tried to set the target to something else, like `my_timestamp`, in case the value of `@timestamp` is being overwritten, but that didn't work either.

Could you help me understand why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZZ is used to [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) "colon in between hour and minute offsets" so you should use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+ZZ".

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I resolved it now with your help! It was "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ" without the '+' !